# MYSQL Inner Join two table over two keys

Tags: mysql, inner-join

I am doing a query to return all users shopping carts, stored in the sb_carts table. The product information stored in sb_carts is referenced over two keys product_sku and school_id. It needs to reference both to return a unique product with unique stock levels etc.

When I execute the following query it returns one row, I am expecting 3 rows.
I have tried breaking the inner join into two separate joins but this still returns only 1 result. joining only on one key has the desired result, but may be retuning the wrong product. A left join returns 3 rows but some data is missing product specific

Here is a simplified example of what I am doing

```
SELECT sb_carts.product_sku
FROM sb_carts 
INNER JOIN sb_products ON sb_products.sku = sb_carts.product_sku 
AND sb_products.school_id = sb_carts.school_id
WHERE sb_carts.order_id = 0 
AND sb_carts.user_id = 2 
GROUP BY sb_carts.cart_id
```

The Full Query looks like

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT sb_carts.cart_id) as quantity, 
sb_carts.* FROM sb_carts 
INNER JOIN sb_children ON sb_children.child_id = sb_carts.child_id 
INNER JOIN sb_school_entities ON sb_school_entities.school_id   = sb_children.school_id 
INNER JOIN sb_products ON sb_products.sku = sb_carts.product_sku 
AND sb_products.school_id = sb_carts.school_id LEFT JOIN sb_houses ON sb_children.house_id = sb_houses.id 
LEFT JOIN sb_refund_cart ON sb_carts.cart_id = sb_refund_cart.cart_id 
WHERE sb_carts.order_id = 0 
AND sb_carts.user_id = 2 
GROUP BY sb_carts.child_id, sb_carts.product_sku, sb_carts.school_id 
ORDER BY sb_children.dob_year, sb_children.dob_month, sb_children.dob_day ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is most likely `GROUP BY`. This will return only one record per cart ID, even if there are multiple products in the cart. To get what you want, try this:

```
SELECT sb_carts.cart_id, sb_carts.product_sku
FROM sb_carts 
INNER JOIN sb_products ON sb_products.sku = sb_carts.product_sku 
AND sb_products.school_id = sb_carts.school_id
WHERE sb_carts.order_id = 0 
AND sb_carts.user_id = 2 
ORDER BY sb_carts.cart_id
```

That will return two columns (the cart ID and SKU) instead of one, and all the items for the one cart ID will appear as consecutive rows in the query.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly the case. MySQL doesn't force you to use aggregate functions if you use GROUP BY (unlike MS-SQL for example, where that query would not be valid)

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using the `Group By` statement? If you are not using a function in the `Select` like `Sum`, `AVG`, etc makes no sense for your porpouse.
So, try running the query without the `Group By` statement :-)

Hope it helps!

Santi! :-)

Comment: My full query make use of count to group similar products together to act as quantity.


SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT sb_carts.cart_id) as quantity,

Answer (score 0):

Mysql INNER JOIN on multiple keys:

```
SELECT * from table1 as t1
INNER JOIN table2 as t2
ON CONCAT(t1.key1, t2.key2)=CONCAT(t2.key1, t2.key2);
```

What we are doing here is combining two key's values and making it look like it is one key.